# Swagger documentation not working for Express server

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, swagger, jsdoc

So basically I have an `Express` API that I've been working on and recently I got the idea to implement a documentation for it. I chose Swagger and JSDoc to do this as it is quick and easy. However the documentation won't work. Here is how I've implemented it so far.

docs.ts:

```
import swaggerJSDoc, { Options } from "swagger-jsdoc";

const swaggerOptions: Options = {
   definition: {
      info: {
         title: "Project Nonya Documentation.",
         description: "Documentation for the Project Nonya API",
         contact: {
            name: "Joe Mama",
         },
         version: "6.9.0",
      },
   },
   apis: ["./routes/*.routes.ts"],
};

export const swaggerDocs = swaggerJSDoc(swaggerOptions);
```

router.ts:

```
...

import swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express";
import { swaggerDocs } from "./docs";

...

app.use("/api/documentation", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));

...
```

When I got to the docs endpoint, the documentation does appear, however its keeps saying `No Operations defined in spec!`. Here is one of the files in the routes folder.

testing.routes.ts:

```
import express, { Router } from "express";
import { testing} from "../controllers/testing/testing.controller";

const router: Router = express.Router();

/**
 * @swagger
 * /:
 *   get:
 *     description: Why you no work?
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Returns nothing cause this shit won't work.
 */
router.post("/testing/:id", testing);

export default router;
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out. The directories are like this: `src/docs.ts`, `src/router.ts`, and `src/routes/testing.router.ts`.

**Side Question**

Since I am using TypeScript, I obviously have to compile the code into JavaScript. However in the apis array in `docs.ts`, I specify files with a `*.routes.ts`. Would I have to change this to `*routes.js`.

Thank You!

Comment: For your side question,  I am pretty sure you don't have to change the path. It will get resolved automatically when it gets executed or compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this Github issue to be the solution to my problem.

https://github.com/Surnet/swagger-jsdoc/issues/150

Comment: Oh, saved me a lot! Thanks.

For me, `'src/api/controllers/*.ts'` worked perfectly. For some reason, it does not want me to start the path with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem. Although my problem is javascript specific not typescript. The bug happened because of the the routes path I defined.

```js
const options = {
  swaggerDefinition,
  apis: ["./routes/*.js"],
};
```

My be the problem happened because of wildcard path not matching with my routes.

To solve this problem I specify the exact path.

```js
const options = {
  swaggerDefinition,
  apis: ["./routes/users/userRoutes.js"],
};
```